# JSF + Hibernate Form Issues

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I have a Hibernate entity class that I'm using as part of a form.

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "Contests")
public class Contest implements Serializable, Cloneable {
private Long id;
private String name;

 ...
}
```

I then create the object through a managed bean.  I then reference the managed bean in the form.  However, each time a form post is done to the object, it does a hibernate select and loses its values.  Is there a way for hibernate to detach the object and let me persist it when I want too?

Thanks, Graeme.

Comment: When you create the object manually, Hibernate won't handle it. Maybe you're doing another operations in your managed bean that you haven't posted.

Comment: what does the facelet/jsp look like?  i'm guessing you're doing some heavy lifting in a mutator/accessor rather than marshalling via action and using the mutator/accessor to just communicate with the jsf layer.  

can you edit the post and add the jsf that references the bean?  also post the controller as well.  that will help the community help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm dumb.  All I needed to do was an ajax update on the form, and wha-la it fixed it.  Thanks for the responses.